# Include only selection of a layer in a QGIS aggregate formula in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

The following collects the chainage along a road at the start of a segment.

```
aggregate(layer:='DSC_Roads_10m_Chainage.tab', aggregate:='max', expression:="distance",
          filter:= intersects(buffer($geometry,10,10), start_point(geometry(@parent))))
```

However since the source dataset has the chainage of all roads in the network, sometimes if the Chainage value along another road (B) is closer to the start of road A, it gets the value from B.

[image]
Note the label is RoadMntnc + the value of the expression (ie chainage at start point of segment).

In the example above both Jones and Syndicate should have a value of 0 as it's the start but it's getting a value from the connecting road instead.

Is it possible to have

```
aggregate(layer:='DSC_Roads_10m_Chainage.tab', group_by := 'RoadMntnc', aggregate:='max', expression:="distance",filter:= intersects(buffer($geometry,10,10), start_point(geometry(@parent))))
```

that's based on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/59

Where A is the layer the field calculator is processing and B. is the dataset it's referring to?

I can't run an intersect without a buffer as the chainage point may not be on the start of a segment.

UPDATE based on Kazuhito's answer

[image]

The yellow road section should be Syndicate Rd 640 instead of 650 as it's closer.

Comment: How does it look if you change `expression:="distance"` to `expression:="distance" * (attribute(@parent, 'RoadMntnc') = attribute($currentfeature, 'RoadMntnc'))` ... sorry I have not tested it myself.

Comment: Thanks - much better but now in some places it's still not using the nearest. I'll update the question in a few mins to reflect this.

Comment: Since the chainage is 10m, if I reduce the buffer to 5m -the code snippet you sent works fine. Can you explain what '* (attribute(@parent, 'RoadMntnc')' does?

Comment: Yes, the `attribute(A) = attribute(B)` part compares the `'RoadMntnc'` fields from both layers, then returns 1 if they match, and 0 if not. Multiplying 1 will retain your "distance" value but 0 will negate that. Overall, it works like a conditional statement.